# Elasticsearch unavailable when emptying garbage collector?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, garbage-collection

I have an Elasticsearch cluster made of two nodes. A (live) website directly uses this cluster, continuously running search and index queries on my ES cluster.

My problem is that, on a regular (and unpredictable) basis, **the whole cluster becomes unavailable when one of the node empties the garbage collector**. The message I get from the node log looks like

```
[2015-07-01 06:43:19,525][INFO ][monitor.jvm] [my_node] [gc][old][205450][116]
duration [5.7s], collections [1]/[6.3s], total [5.7s]/[1m],
memory [22.3gb]->[4.9gb]/[30.9gb],
all_pools {[young] [392.9mb]->[17.2mb]/[665.6mb]}
{[survivor] [29.1mb]->[0b]/[83.1mb]}
{[old] [21.9gb]->[4.9gb]/[30.1gb]}
```

From what I understand (I'm not a java person), this lines indicates that ES is emptying its garbage collector. So, **during those 5.7 seconds, the node is not responding, nor is my cluster, nor is my website**. This downtime happens 5 to 10 times a day.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this downtime unavoidable? Should I add an Elasticsearch load balancer (i.e. a node with data=false, master=false) to the cluster and have my website point to this loadbalancer? Or should I add another kind of load balancer (HAProxy?) in front of my nodes? Or does this mean there's something wrong with the servers, the data?

Thanks a lot in advance

Some info about the cluster configuration

- Elasticsearch 1.6.0 cluster made of 2 nodes (5 shards, 1 replica)
- The cluster contains ~10 million docs, occupying ~30 Gb.
- Each node is a 64Gb RAM server with a MAX_HEAP_SIZE set to 31g
- The website runs ~300 search queries per second and ~100 index queries per second
- The JVM heap usage is always between 50% and 75%, never above

Comment: Yes, during old GC the node on which the GC runs is frozen. This is how it is regarding Java. Regarding tuning this is not easy :-). There are many things to look at and is not easy for you to share those things.

Comment: If the heap usage is always between 50% and 75% the Garbage Collector shouldn't run that long (and from the log you posted it looks like the heap was almost full when the GC ran for 6 seconds). Allocating more RAM to the heap will help, but there might be other factors at work that cause so much RAM being used in the first place. Those factors will be hard to track and/or fix.

Comment: Also, make sure you always run the latest Java and Elasticsearch versions if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm confident I'm running the latest ES and Java versions. If this downtime is unavoidable on a node level, how can I make sure that the whole cluster stays up ? I thought that adding a node would fix this issue but it seems that a node-level downtime always becomes a cluster-level downtime ... Hence my question on putting a load balancer in front of the nodes

Comment: The ES documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) says the max heap size should not be above 31 GB : do you think I could still increase it ?

Comment: No :-). There is a good reason for that limit. How is your swap usage? Is this bare metal or virtualized environment?

Comment: I am having the same issue when I upgraded to ES 1.6 from 1.1 and Java 6 to Java 7u67. I am suspecting it has more to do with java version than anything else. @benoit did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Since when GC runs heap goes from 21.9gb to 4.9gb, I doubt that heap usage is between 50% and 75%, most likely GC is triggered on 75% and then it drops down to ~15%.
If you don't have Marvel installed - install it and monitor params like segments count and heap usage. To lower the segments count run Optimize on indices that have little or no writes (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-optimize.html).
If you continue to have slowdowns when GC runs try lowering heap size. I know it sounds counterproductive, but in this case it makes sense. There is a good writeup on the subject on Elastic site - https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble